# Proof of if $A \times B = A \times C$, and $A \neq \varnothing$, then $B=C$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

Proof: suppose $A \times B = A \times C$

Then $\frac{A \times B}{A} = \frac{A \times C}{A}$

Therefore $B=C$

Is this proof valid?

Comment: What does the horizontal line mean?

Comment: Almost surely not.  Your question suggests that $A$ is a set.  I've never heard of anyone dividing by a set.

Comment: Also, I think there may be two typos in your title.  Should it say "if $A \times B = A \times C$..." like in the body of the question?

Comment: What sort of objects are $A$, $B$, and $C$?  Since we do not know this, we don't know what the infix binary operator $\times$ is doing. Define your terms. Is $\times$ a Cartesian product?

Comment: @ncmathsadist That's a good point.  I assumed that $A$, $B$, and $C$ were sets because of the assumption $A \ne \emptyset$ in the title.

Comment: I find it curious that this theorem is so similar to the equivalent one for plain real numbers: if $ab=ac$ and $a\ne0$, then $b=c$.

Comment: This proof does not work but it almost does. If we take the free group on the sets involved, we get $$\mathbb{Z}[A]\otimes\mathbb{Z}[B]\sim\mathbb{Z}[A\times B]=\mathbb{Z}[A\times C]\sim \mathbb{Z}[A]\otimes\mathbb{Z}[C].$$ When we quotient out both sides by $\mathbb{Z}[A]$, we get $$\mathbb{Z}[A]\sim\frac{\mathbb{Z}[A\times B]}{\mathbb{Z}[A]}=\frac{\mathbb{Z}[A\times C]}{\mathbb{Z}[A]}\sim\mathbb{Z}[C].$$

Comment: @BabyDragon I assume you meant to write $\Bbb Z[B]\sim\frac{\Bbb Z[A\times B]}{\Bbb Z[A]}$. What is $\Bbb Z$ here, and how does it relate to the free group? Also, if I understand correctly, you are proving that $|B|=|C|$, right (by showing that $\Bbb Z[B]\sim\Bbb Z[C]$)?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Yes, I sometimes get lost in the mathjax. I should have said free abelian group. Yes, one should then tensor both sides with $\mathbb{Z}/2$, and count elements. This shows that $|B|=|C|$, but not that $B=C$. The point I wanted to make is that sometimes such divisions do make sense, just not in the category of sets.

Comment: The title is bad, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument, while suggestive, does not mean anything because there is no division operation defined for sets.  If in addition to assuming that $A$ is nonempty, we assume that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all finite, we do have something like what you wrote for the *cardinalities* of the sets:
$$ \frac{\left|A \times B\right|}{\left|A\right|} = \left|B\right|.$$
Even so, you are asked to prove that $B$ and $C$ are equal, not just that they have the same cardinality.  So you will need a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that two sets are equal, we need to show that every element of one is an element of the other. Since by assumption, $A\ne\emptyset$, fix an element $a\in A$, and now consider any $x\in B$. By the definition of the cartesian product, $\langle a,x\rangle\in A\times B$. But $A\times B=A\times C$, so $\langle a,x\rangle\in A\times C$. Again by definition, this means that $a\in A$ and $x\in C$, which shows that $B\subseteq C$. Arguing the same say with $B,C$ swapped, we find $B=C$.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good thing to post a correct proof in response to the question "is this proof valid?"---perhaps the OP would rather work on it alone for a while after finding out that the answer is "no".

Comment: @TrevorWilson When the OP is wildly off the mark, I consider the appropriate course of action to be a well-documented correct proof with explanation, in order to show how to approach this and similar problems. If the OP has the idea mostly right, it can make sense to point out errors instead, but to simply state "you can't divide sets" here will just put him back at step 0, not sure how to approach the problem correctly.

Comment: Ok, that makes some sense.  It sounds like you have considered the issue at least as much as I have.

Comment: @StefanSmith That's only a productive method if the OP is responsive enough that you can gauge the hints properly. So far, he hasn't said anything, and hasn't even fixed the typo in the title. Thus I am classing this as a PSQ and moving on. Hopefully the OP eventually comes back and gains some deeper understanding from this answer. If not, well, I can't spoon-feed someone forever.

Comment: @Stefan As I have stated, I do have an ethic for when and how I answer PSQ's (problem statement questions, a topic of heated debate on meta), so don't worry about how I respond to other questions. If you see something you disagree with, you can bring it up on the relevant question.